# Getting issue “failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate `solana_program`?”

Tags: solana-program, error, bug

I am getting the following error when compiling a Solana program:

```
$ npm run build

> hello-world@1.0.0 build
> cargo build-bpf --manifest-path=./src/program/Cargo.toml --bpf-out-dir=./dist/program

BPF SDK: /Users/matt/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.8.6/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
   Compiling program v0.0.1 (/Users/matt/code/solana/hello-world/src/program)
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate `solana_program`?
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use solana_program::{
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `solana_program`?

error[E0432]: unresolved import `borsh`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
  |     ^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `borsh`?

error[E0432]: unresolved import `solana_program`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use solana_program::{
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `solana_program`?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had this issue. Took me a while to figure out, but in the end, the reason was that I was missing an edition value in Cargo.toml.

I had:

```
[package]
name = "program"
version = "0.0.1"
```

But needed:

```
[package]
name = "program"
version = "0.0.1"
edition = "2021"
```

Please take note that you can choose any name and package for this.

When you use cargo new, the edition is automatically established; however, I once erased it while organizing the manifest. For backward compatibility, Rust thinks the edition is 2015 if it is not specified; nevertheless, this creates issues with the compilation of the Solana program.